# Type of "htmlAttributes" in TextBoxFor and how to add more attributes to it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

I've added an extension method as a helper for my MVC view and want to add another attribute to any attributes it already has. Here's the signature of the standard TextBoxFor method (and of mine, except mine is called "TextBoxForWithTitle"):

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

The last parameter, htmlAttributes, looks like a name value pair. When I hover over it (during runtime), its value is "{ class = emailtextbox }" which I added in the Razor view. How do I add another name/value attribute to this in my extension method? I tried casting it to a Dictionary, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access it as a **RouteValueDictionary**:

```
IDictionary<string, object> newAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
```

This allows you to add new items in your code:

```
newAttributes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("id", id));
```

Answer (score 5):

It shows that it's type of object. How do you initialize a new object? `new { [properties go here] }`. So we are down to this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeId, new { @class = "whatever-class", @id = 5, data_customAttr = "customAttribute"})
```

Note that if you want `data-` attributes, use `_` instead of `-`. They will be converted.